# how to create a jira ticket from PHP application

Tags: php, rest, soap, jira

I am trying to create a system that can create jira tickets from our application, which is independent of jira.
I have heard of REST API and Soap API but I dont really know how to use these api?
Is there anything that can help me to get a kick start?
any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation. http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

A REST api usually accepts HTTP request with data and sends something back. And there are plenty of REST clients written in PHP, so you won't need to do it again. Just have a look at packagist.org and search for "rest" to find about 14 pages worth of related stuff, with "Guzzle" being the most used: https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: Thank you Sven, 
But, I am using CI framework, so Guzzle works for CI framework?? I don't know how to implement guzzle in my application.
Is there anything else that can help me??
JIRA API is not so well documented so I am finding it hard to implement.

Comment: Using one framework does not prevent you from using another or parts of another. After all, this is just PHP. But what I've heard is that CodeIgniter is sort of dead: http://heybigname.com/2012/05/06/why-codeigniter-is-dead/

Answer (score 0):

Read up :)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217758/what-is-a-rest-api